# Full functional audio player using Web Audio API?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, web-audio-api

I'm carrying out a feasibility study to create an audio player for windows phone. I could go for native implementation or web view based implementation.

I'm wondering weather Web Audio API could full-fill the following requirements.

- Music Playback with high quality? Will there a huge difference between native playback quality vs Web Audio playback quality ?
- Web Audio API support for Equalizer ?

What would your choice be (Native or Web based) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does windows phone support WebAudio?  Certainly Internet Explorer does not (yet).

But I think the answer to your two questions would be yes, if WebAudio were implemented correctly.  You have to create your own equalizer, but that's not hard.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible, instead web audio provides higher quality playback to your music files, If you need full functional player, then you can get it here
https://github.com/davinder17s/unplay

Demo:
https://davinder17s.github.io/unplay/